# Cómo puedo ocultar y mostrar el contenido de más de 4 botones en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cada botón con información diferente, cuando oprima 1 los otros 3 se oculten y al elegir otro se oculten los demás.

Dejo el código donde tengo 2 botones funcionando quise añadir otro botón y lo agrega pero no hace el funcionamiento de mostrar su respectivo contenido en el div. En pocas palabras el tercer boton no muestra su contenido. si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería :).

Muchas gracias.

````
class Ejemplo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { checked: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-6  mb-2">
          <div
            className="btn-group btn-group-sm"
            role="group"
            aria-label="Basic example"
          >
            {/* Este es el boton 1 */}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-nquote"
              className="button2"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(false)}
            >
              Todos mis cursos
            </button>

            {/* Este es el boton 2 */}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-flex"
              className="button1"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
            >
              Recursos
            </button>
            {/*Este es el boton 3*/}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-flex"
              className="button1"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
            >
              Tareas
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span>
       

          ```
````

Comment: Seria de mucha utilidad si pudieras mostrar parte de tu código junto a lo que ya has intentado

Comment: Parea recrear lo que mencionas exactamente, estaria bien que dieras un poco mas de contexto para poder hacerte llegar un ejemplo que sea 100% igual a tu problematic, mientras te dejo el link de como ocultar y mostrar un objeto simple en React, es un pequeño ejemplo que encontre en CodePen que justamente muestra y oculta un objeto utilizando REACT... Puedes hacerte una cuenta en codepen y asi subir tu ejemplo ahi mismo, Saludos espero te sirva de algo [Espero te sirva](https://codepen.io/aut0maat10/pen/MGePJX)

Comment: ya subi una parte del codigo. ahi los botones se muestran pero a la hora de llamarlo no hace su funcion de ejecucion. solo el boton 3 (el boton 1 y 2 si se muestran con su respectivo contenido.